# Eclipse (STS) MVC 3.0.5 + Tiles 2.2.2 project dependency management issue

Tags: spring, tiles, dependency-management

For some reason I cannot use maven or gradle dependecy management. I am trying to use Tiles with Spring MVC, I get the following Exception on tcserver startup:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/startup/BasicTilesInitializer

Here is my dependencies folder:
[image: Dependencies]

Also Eclipse points out this Error in my `layout.jsp`

> The tag handler class for 
>        "tiles:insertAttribute" (org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag) was not found on the Java Build 
>        Path

Can anyone point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the SOURCE jars in you project lib folder. But you need to use the normal once with the compiled classes.

`tiles-core-2.2.2.jar` instead of `tiles-core-2.2.2-sources.jar`

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, but it should at least work within eclipse. I haven't deployed yet.

Comment: No, this does not work with eclipse, because Eclipse does not compile sources from jar files. In eclipse, without maven, you need to add the normal jars to the lib folder, and then you can attach the sources jars for each jar via "properties"/"build path"

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven to manage dependency then add below to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Else Download following jars and add it to `/WEB-INF/lib`

- [tiles-core.2.2.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tiles/tiles-core/2.2.2/tiles-core-2.2.2.jar)
- [tiles-api.2.2.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tiles/tiles-api/2.2.2/tiles-api-2.2.2.jar)

and also add this transitive dependency as tiles use on Slf4j

- [slf4j-jdk14.1.5.8.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.5.8/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.8.jar)

Comment: If you take a look at the image I have attached http://i.stack.imgur.com/E4FiJ.jpg. Those are already added in my `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.